# Is there a way to query resource values on an Android device?

Tags: android

I want to get some internal resource values that can depend on the SIM in the device:

- the integers in the array with key `config_tether_upstream_types`,
- the strings in the array with key `config_gpsParameters`, and
- the string with key `config_mms_user_agent_profile_url`.

For example, the Nexus 6 has [this base configuration file](https://android.googlesource.com/device/moto/shamu/+/master/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml), but a value in [a SIM-dependent file](https://android.googlesource.com/device/moto/shamu/+/master/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res) can override a base value.

If I just wanted the values I mentioned above, I could write and install an app hard coded to get the values from `com.android.internal.R`. (Where does an Android device store these values?) But is there a generic way to query any resource value?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... You need to know the base value even when this base value is overridden in another resource file ? (that's your question ?)

Comment: No, I want the resolved value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("config_mms_user_agent_profile_url", "string", "com.android.internal")
CharSequence string = Resources.getSystem().getString(id);
```